# How to execute a query inside getchanges

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

```
public virtual SyncContext GetChanges(SyncGroupMetadata groupMetadata, SyncSession syncSession)
{
    SyncContext gtc=new SyncContext ();

    ("I want to execute "SELECT * FROM Talename" here)

    return gtc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're asking if there's anything in the Sync Framework SDK to allow you to call/execute some SQL statements, the answer is there's none.

if you want to execute the something, you have to establish the connection yourself (or reuse the connection from Sync Fx), fire your queries and retrieve the results yourself (e.g., ADO.NET, EF, etc...)